# tx_news where to get translated xlf files

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I searching translated versions of the tx_news translation files. When I open `ext/news/Resources/Private/language/` all I find are the default (english) versions of the xlf Files.

I am sure there are translation files in other languages for tx_news, but I was not able to find them. How can I find them? Or can I get them somehow in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get them in the backend - there is the `Language` module in the menu, where you can set the list of languages for your installation, and download or update the translation files.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but as I want the backend in english for everyone I was not sure if this will be the right way for me or if something else get changed. I guess I will just try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more complete. The translations are served by the translation server, therefore only the default translations are shipped with the extension itself.

As for the core and most extensions, translations are fetched by the **Language module** in the TYPO3 backend